# Relaxed Memory Model for Interpreted Languages

Tags: compiler-optimization, interpreter, memory-model

Interpreted Languages, logically execute each line by applying the state available before the line and hence get the state after the execution. I wonder if the relaxed memory model is applicable for interpreted Languages.

I searched for interpreted and relaxed memory model but did not hit any relevant searches.

Comment: Interpreter overhead is normally so high that any savings from less ordering of loads/stores is insignificant.  Or even negative savings if you did it like C++ with an extra arg to certain functions that the interpreter would have to handle, instead of having separate function names like `atomic_relaxed_load(shared_var)` vs. `atomic_seq_cst_load(shared_var)`.  Also, most interpreted languages are not designed around multiple threads with the ability to do lock-free atomic operations, since their objects (and thus internal data structures) are higher-level than a machine `int`.

Comment: What is an interpreted language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interpreter overhead is normally so high that any savings from less ordering of loads/stores probably wouldn't be very significant.  Or even negative savings if you did it like C++ with an optional extra arg to functions like `shared_var.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)` that the interpreter would have to handle, instead of having separate function names like `atomic_relaxed_load(shared_var)` vs. `atomic_seq_cst_load(shared_var)`.

Also, most interpreted languages are not designed around multiple threads with the ability to do lock-free atomic operations, since their objects (and thus internal data structures) are higher-level than a machine `int`.

That's why CPython for example takes/releases the Global Interpreter Lock around each statement, so threading is AFAIK only useful for I/O and stuff like that, where different threads can be blocked on different things. (Or calling a C library function to do some computation or something.)  If you want your interpreted language to be able to have multiple threads interpreting at once, you'd have to design the internals from the ground up to make that safe.

(I'd guess there might be some interpreter like that for some language, but I don't remember reading about any of the major mainstream ones like CPython being like that.  Even the node.js environment for Javascript which uses the V8 JIT engine doesn't AFAIK support running multiple threads at once.  Languages like Java do, though, which is also a VM but was designed to be a bit lower level than Javascript or Python.)

Comment: I understand your reasoning for the performance benefits that we may gain on allowing relaxed memory model for interpreted languages.  I am wondering if any reordering is even semantically correct for interpreted languages (excluding JIT).

Comment: Not introducing weak memory model for interpreted languages is because how the interpreters work, or it is because that the performance gains are very small.

Comment: @Abhishek: If you're designing a new language, you get to define the semantics of how threads can communicate with each other in that language.  Your memory model can include operations weaker than seq_cst if you want.

Comment: @Abhishek re: performance: Relaxed and acq/rel are useful in C++ to reduce overhead. In an interpreter, overhead is already really high so reducing a small amount of it is a pretty minor thing.  The performance gain might be quite significant if you have a writer that very frequently does an atomic update of something, but rarely reads. e.g. maybe 20x faster for an x86 loop doing `foo.store(1, release)` vs. `foo.store(1, seq_cst)`, `xchg mem,reg` throughput vs. mov store, not draining the store buffer. Maybe less bad on AArch64 where seq_cst stores are cheaper.